# Convert Python to Java Opencv

Tags: java, android, python, opencv

I am trying to convert this code snippet to Java for days now

ef transformation_from_points(points1, points2):
        """
        points1 and points2 are 68 X 2 matrices.

```
    Return an affine transformation [s * r | T] such that:
        sum ||s*r*p1,i + T - p2,i||^2
    is minimized.

    output is a 3x3 matrix.
    """
    # Solve the procrustes problem by subtracting centroids, scaling by the
    # standard deviation, and then using the SVD to calculate the rotation.

    # print("point1 Type = {0}".format(type(points1)))
    # print("point2 Type = {0}".format(type(points2)))

    points1 = points1.astype(np.float64)
    points2 = points2.astype(np.float64)

    # print("point1 = {0}".format(points1))
    # print("point2 = {0}".format(points2))

    c1 = np.mean(points1, axis=0)
    c2 = np.mean(points2, axis=0)

    # print("SCALAR ", c1, c2)

    #print("c1 = {0}".format(c1))
    # print("c2 = {0}".format(c1))

    points1 -= c1
    points2 -= c2
    #
    # print("AFTER SUBTRACTION ", points1)
    # print("AFTER SUBTRACTION ", points2)

    s1 = np.std(points1)
    s2 = np.std(points2)
    #
    # print("AFTER STANDARD DEVIATION ", s1)
    # print("AFTER STANDARD DEVIATION", s2)

    points1 /= s1
    points2 /= s2

    # print("AFTER DIVISION ", points1)
    # print("AFTER DIVISION ", points2)

    # print("Points1.T = {0}".format(points1.T))
    # print("Points2.T = {0}".format(points2.T))

    u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(points1.T * points2)

    print("POINT 1 ", points1.shape)
    print("POINT 1 TRANSPOSE ", (points1.T).shape)
    print("POINT 2 ", points2.shape)
    print("POINT 1 TRANS POINT 2 ", (points1.T * points2).shape)

    #
    # print("POINT 3 ", points1.shape)
    # print("POINT 3 ", type(points1))

    # The r we seek is in fact the transpose of the one given by u * vt. This
    # is because the above formulation assumes the matrix goes on the right
    # (with row vectors) where as our solution requires the matrix to be on the
    # left (with column vectors).
    r = (u * vt).T

    return np.vstack([np.hstack(((s2 / s1) * r, c2.T - (s2 / s1) * r * c1.T)), np.matrix([0., 0., 1.])])
```

this is how far I have gotten

I have not been able to perform the Matrix multiplication

Please what am I doing wrong??

public Mat transformationFromPoints(ArrayList selfieImageLandmarks,
                                        ArrayList hairModelImageLandmark){

```
    org.opencv.core.Point selfieImage [] = new org.opencv.core.Point[selfieImageLandmarks.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < selfieImageLandmarks.size(); i++){
        selfieImage[i] = new org.opencv.core.Point(selfieImageLandmarks.get(i).x,
                                                    selfieImageLandmarks.get(i).y);
    }

    org.opencv.core.Point hairModel [] = new org.opencv.core.Point[hairModelImageLandmark.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < selfieImageLandmarks.size(); i++){
        hairModel[i] = new org.opencv.core.Point(hairModelImageLandmark.get(i).x,
                                                    hairModelImageLandmark.get(i).y);
    }

    MatOfPoint point1 = new MatOfPoint(selfieImage);
    MatOfPoint point2 = new MatOfPoint(hairModel);

    MatOfDouble mean1 = new MatOfDouble();
    MatOfDouble s1 = new MatOfDouble();
    Core.meanStdDev(point1, mean1, s1);
    Scalar stdScalar1 = new Scalar(s1.get(0, 0)[0]);


    MatOfDouble mean2 = new MatOfDouble();
    MatOfDouble s2 = new MatOfDouble();
    Core.meanStdDev(point2, mean2, s2);
    Scalar stdScalar2 = new Scalar(s2.get(0, 0)[0]);

    Core.divide(point1, stdScalar1, point1);
    Core.divide(point2, stdScalar2, point2);

    Mat src = new Mat();

    Core.gemm(point1.t(), point2, 1, new Mat(), 0, src);


    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post only the relevant parts of your code? Have you tried matrix.mul() function? If yes, what is the problem?

Comment: Core.gemm(tranps, point2, 1, new Mat(), 0, src); I am trying to perform multiplication using Core.gemm() method. I am using opencv. there is no matrix.mul() function in open cv

Comment: `mul()` is a method in the Matrix class. You can call e.g. `mat1.mul(mat2)`. If this doesn't help you please clarify your question. What exactly in your code does not work as you expect it. What output do you get, and what output do you expect.

Comment: I am simply trying to mutiply matrix a by matrix b

Comment: point1 and point2 are both 68x1 matrix. I am trying to multiply the transpose of point1 by point2.

Comment: mat1.mul(mat2) ====> throws an exception----------- error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function void cv::arithm_op(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, int, void (**)(const uchar*, size_t, const uchar*, size_t, uchar*, size_t, int, int, void*), bool, void*, int)